# OpenLayers module only displays latitude/longitude instead of map

Tags: views, nodes, javascript

So I began experimenting with OpenLayers because I'm creating a content type that requires it.

I followed the [Step-by-step instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1481374) from the docs (added geofield to node, create data overlay view, cloned and set up my map and created a page view to display the map)... but what I actually need is to somehow embedded the maps for each post. What is the next step for something like this? Right now in each node I see the node pictures and this: POINT (-0.138513 50.8239).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your display settings for your content type and choose 'OpenLayers', then click the gear icon and Select which OpenLayers map you would like to use. Only maps which have the geofield placeholder layer may be selected. If your preferred map is not here, add the geofield placeholder layer to it first.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it doesn't pop up the marker on the map. For that, you have to create a view for that content type to create an open layer overlay. Then, you can easily enable that layer as you did it for placeholder layer. In the behaviour section, you just need to enable your openlayer.